# Left outer join issue with mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code below, with which I select first all id's from table users then I select and find the total sum of points from the coupon table which belong to this user, then I also select all points that belong to this user from the retailer table. Then I do the difference between this sums.

But something is going wrong, I get completely different points.

```
$query4 = 'SELECT u.*, sum(c.points) as total_sum1, sum(r.basket_value) as total_sum 
           FROM users u 
           left outer join coupon c on u.user_id=c.user_id
           left outer join retailer r on u.user_id=r.user_id 
           group by user_id';
$result4 = mysql_query($query4) or die(mysql_error());

$total1=0;
$total=0;
$total2=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result4)) {
    $total1 += $row['total_sum1'];
    $total += $row['total_sum'];
    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo  $total2=$total-$total1;
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";

    echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>";
}
```

Sample of the output:

```
total points remaining    |   user_id
0                             9839467227
0                             9853125067
0                             9937770769
0                             9974837329
222060                        A101
0                             A102
0                             A103
0                             A104
```

Comment: To be true i don't know.. i was suggested to do like this..

Comment: what output are you getting? and what output you want to get?

Comment: I need to get the remaining point for each user, the difference between total sum and total sum1 for each user, well, i get numbers, but they are almost the same for all users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your problem is:

```
    $total1 += $row['total_sum1'];
    $total += $row['total_sum'];
```

`$total1` and `$total` is appending all record for all user. I think it must be:

```
    $total1 = $row['total_sum1'];
    $total = $row['total_sum'];
```

Try this:

```
 SELECT u.*, SUM(c.ts) AS total_sum1, SUM(r.bv) AS total_sum 
FROM users u 
LEFT JOIN 
 (SELECT user_id ,SUM(points) AS ts FROM coupon GROUP BY user_id) c 
 ON u.user_id=c.user_id 
LEFT JOIN 
 (SELECT user_id ,SUM(basket_value) AS bv FROM retailer GROUP BY user_id) r 
ON u.user_id=r.user_id 
GROUP BY u.user_id;
```

Comment: Thank you.. it still won't give me exact values, do you think there might be something with the query, maybe not left outer join or something...
I could do this in separate queries but it's better if i keep all the queries in just one..

Comment: @al_alb i could help more if you can give a sample output, and what output do you expect.

Comment: i edited the answer, the idea is, a user's points are stored in the retailer table, which mean, each time a use rbuys something, there is a new row inserted, with the number of points and the user id, but when the user spends points, this points spent go to the coupon table with the number of points and user id, what i need is to fnd the difference of the total points gained with the total points spent by a user

Comment: Can you please help me on this?

Comment: @al_alb wait i'll check it for you

Comment: The query worked perfectly, i didn't see your answer before :) thank you!